# gnome shut down dropdown button doesn't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, I cannot shut down properly my computer.

Top right corner dropdown button doesn't show properly and all its buttons doesn't work either.

Also before upgrading I had some applications that started on startup time and appeared on bottom left corner as a system tray with an arrow. Now this button does not appear either.

I have tried to reinstall gnome-session, gnome-control-center and gdm3 but nothing seems to solve it.

What can I do?

[image]

**Edit:**
As @popey says after running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` command it says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libsane1: Depends: libsane-common (= 1.0.27-1 ~ experimental3ubuntu2.4) but 1.0.31 + git20210108-xenial0 is going to be installed
```

Comment: It's possible some package is missing. Try opening a terminal and running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` - the caret (^) on the end is important.

Comment: ok, it says: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libsane1: Depends: libsane-common (= 1.0.27-1 ~ experimental3ubuntu2.4) but 1.0.31 + git20210108-xenial0 is going to be installed

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it, as @Popey said I had an unmet dependency I knew about that by using following command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

(the caret (^) on the end is important)

This resulted in the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libsane1: Depends: libsane-common (= 1.0.27-1 ~ experimental3ubuntu2.4) but 1.0.31 + git20210108-xenial0 is going to be installed
```

Then I only had to remove that package by:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge libsane1
```

Note, this will also remove some gnome packages.

And resintall gnome again

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

**UPDATE**

After reinstalling dependencies I still had the same problem. I finally solved it by switching the session type before logging in:[image: switching the session type before logging in to ubuntu on Xorg]

Comment: Why do you have `–` before `purge`?

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Comment: The correct is `--` as it is long option.

Comment: Did you have a PPA enabled or something, which went away in the upgrade?

Comment: yes, some of them, went away in the upgrade and I restored them after fixing this bug.